# How to make Mac OS X Snow Leopard Software Update to use a custom Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, mac, update

I have my Mac OS X 10.6 server, and iI have enabled software update, but now I need my Macbook Air and iMac to update from this server.

I have tried to read about it, but I can't find it, I hope somebody can help me here, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer could be in this related question:

[How do I change the Software Update server address on a client Mac (to use my own server)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/11410/how-do-i-change-the-software-update-server-address-on-a-client-mac-to-use-my-own/70356#70356)

Comment: Tanks a lot, all i need :)