# unmanaged client software update server mac os x uses wrong IP address

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, osx-yosemite

Using directions from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202030) I successfully have had my Yosemite server serve out software updates to unmanaged clients. The server also serves DHCP and DNS and works correctly in all respects, and always has.

Due to circumstances I was forced to change the server's IP address from 192.168.178.201 to 192.168.178.199.

In order to keep serving updates locally, I deleted the preferences on clients as directed per link above, restarted and re-set the prefs file on the client. The preferences read back correctly pointing to 192.168.178.199, also DNS server points to that address (and works).

Since then, launching App Store to obtain software updates, App Store complains , "Didn't get a response from the Software Update server (192.168.178.201)", leading me to believe there is another location where the server's address is kept.

Short of using [this dns trick](https://serverfault.com/questions/11410/how-do-i-change-the-software-update-server-address-on-a-client-mac-to-use-my-ow) I don't know a solution. Any hints as to where the cause of the aforementioned problem could be found are welcome.

Comment: Your reference to Apple's directions helped me "`sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently sometimes it is not enough to just perform the "sudo defaults" commands.
Removing a file in possibly two locations solves this problem.  They are

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
```

Quit AppStore, delete the plist files (trash them, empty trash), log out, log back in again and AppStore will re-create them. If necessary, point your client to your own swupdate server as explained [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202030).

Comment: There is another place where this file can live: `/Library/Managed Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist`

Comment: You are spot on. This is indeed the offending plist. In this folder Managed Preferences subfolders were created too, with user names and copies of the offending plist. I guess I have a lot of reading up to do to understand how it got there.